# Find duplicates in a hash, store grouped in a new hash

Tags: perl, sorting, hashmap, duplicates

I have the following hash, and I need to find the duplicates between the top most hash values `6` and `4`. I've tried a few solutions to no avail, and am not too familiar with Perl syntax to make it work.

## The Hash I Have

```
$VAR1 = { 
    '6' => [ '1000', '2000', '4000' ],
    '4' => [ '1000', '2000', '3000' ]
};
```

## The Hash I Need

```
$VAR1 = {
    '6' => ['4000'],
    '4' => ['3000'],
    'Both' => ['1000','2000']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find all common elements, e.g. by deduplicating with a hash.
2. Find all elements that are not common.

Given two arrays `@x`, `@y`, this would mean:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

# find all common elements
my %common;
$common{$_}++ for uniq(@x), uniq(@y); # count all elements
$common{$_} == 2 or delete $common{$_} for keys %common;

# remove entries from @x, @y that are common:
@x = grep { not $common{$_} } @x;
@y = grep { not $common{$_} } @y;

# Put the common strings in an array:
my @common = keys %common;
```

Now all that is left is to do a bit of dereferencing and such, but that should be fairly trivial.

Comment: The output of @common is just a concat of @x and @y, regardless of how similar or dissimilar they are.

Comment: @PatrickRobertSheaO'Connor I'm sorry, it is fixed now: We have to count in how many arrays each element is, then remove those elements for which the count is below the number of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

No need for other modules.  perl hashes are really good for finding uniq or common values

```
my %both;
# count the number of times any element was seen in 4 and 6
$both{$_}++ for (@{$VAR1->{4}}, @{$VAR1->{6}});
for (keys %both) {
  # if the count is one the element isn't in both 4 and 6
  delete $both{$_} if( $both{$_} == 1 );
}
$VAR1->{Both} = [keys %both];
```